# Get Unity WWW response status code

Tags: api, rest, http, response

I'm working with Unity WWW for some Rest API request. But it don't support to get response status (only return text and error). Any solution for it? Thanks!

Comment: For future reference: If you get a 301 redirect followed by an error message, Unity's response headers will contain the 301, not the error. :(

Answer (score 12):

*edit:* Since the time I asked this question, Unity released a new framework for HTTP communications called UnityWebRequest.  It's much more modern than WWW, and provides definitive access to the Response Code, as well as more flexibility around headers, HTTP verbs, etc.  You should probably use that instead of WWW.

---

apparently you need to parse it from the response headers yourself.

this seems to do the trick:

```
public static int getResponseCode(WWW request) {
  int ret = 0;
  if (request.responseHeaders == null) {
    Debug.LogError("no response headers.");
  }
  else {
    if (!request.responseHeaders.ContainsKey("STATUS")) {
      Debug.LogError("response headers has no STATUS.");
    }
    else {
      ret = parseResponseCode(request.responseHeaders["STATUS"]);
    }
  }

  return ret;
}

public static int parseResponseCode(string statusLine) {
  int ret = 0;

  string[] components = statusLine.Split(' ');
  if (components.Length < 3) {
    Debug.LogError("invalid response status: " + statusLine);
  }
  else {
    if (!int.TryParse(components[1], out ret)) {
      Debug.LogError("invalid response code: " + components[1]);
    }
  }

  return ret;
}
```